# LinkExisting Business Page To Facebook App

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched every where for this but the answers i found are all out dated.

My client has a business page that needs to be managed through a C# application. For testing i have created a dev account on facebook , i had created an app and then an app page that automatically links to that app. Through that app i can manage all API calls to send/recieve messages etc using the app id and app secret.

Now i want to link that app to the business page of my client how can i do that? i have tried created another app with same name as the business page of my client , i have changed the category of the business page to "App Page" (as mentioned in few other responses from stackoverflow) but the page never show up in the app page field. 
 How can i link the existing page to my facebook app?

Comment: Managing a page via app has nothing to do with adding the page to the app. (App pages are supposed to present the app to potential users.) What you want, is to implement Facebook login so that the page admin can grant your app the necessary permissions to manage the page.

Comment: hi there, thank you for your reply! ill try that.